# Why is my OpenLayers map not showing on my Android device when it works fine in the browser within an Ionic React project?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, openlayers

I am working on integrating an OpenLayers map inside a Ionic React project. I am able to fully view and manipulate the map when running the application locally in browser. When I run on my device (using adb and Android Studio), the map does not show, but it does take space and markers can be seen on the map.

I have read around and found two links that seem related to my issue. I followed the advice on the [first link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/capacitor-google-map-not-showing-on-android/228390) and set the background transparent. The s[econd link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-maps-not-loading-in-device-but-works-fine-in-browser-ionic4/151222/21) looked a lot like my issue and mentioned the shadow dom, but the thread was closed when the resolution was found to be caused by API key.

I am suspecting the webview to be hidden, but I am not sure how to fix the issue at this point. I tried to set a transparent background to elements (body, IonApp, IonPage, IonContent) in my app without success.

App.tsx

```
const App: React.FC = () => (  
  <IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonRouterOutlet>
        <Route path='/home' component={Home}/>
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
);
```

Home.tsx

```
const Home: React.FC = () => (  
  returnt (<IonPage>
    <IonContent>
      <MapComponent />
    </IonContent>
  </IonPage>)
);
```

MapComponent.tsx (I removed the logic creating the map to keep this readable and since I don't think the issue is coming from there)

```
const App: React.FC = () => (  
    const mapRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
    const [map, setMap] = useState<Map | undefined>();

    useEffect(() => {
        initMap(mapRef)

        return () => {
            map?.setTarget(undefined)
            mapRef.current = null
        }
    }, [])

  function initMap(mapElement) { /* Logic not included to keep this short */ }

  return (
    <div ref={mapRef} style={{ width: '100%', height: '400px', border: 'black 2px solid' }}></div>

  )
);
```

Comment: Try attaching Chrome Devtools and look for two things - is the HTML `Canvas` element there, has a size and is visible - and does OpenLayers say anything in the console

Comment: There is an element for the grid and it has a size, is visible. No error in the console either (not even warnings)

Comment: Try initialising the map with its div element in the constructor, I have had weird problems with `setTarget` in the past. You don't get anything in the `Network` tab - like loading tiles from the server?

Comment: @mmomtchev Were you working with react functional components also? I feel using a constructor in React is discourage in favor of the useEffect hook. Network tab is showing things, but nothing like errors

Comment: You are not using React safe mode? Your component is not really reusable and when in dev mode, React will remount it twice to test this. Try running in production mode to check this.

Comment: No not using React safe mode! Right now, the project is mostly a POC, so just running and testing things. I am also using Ionic, not sure if safe mode will work, but Ill give it a try along with PROD mode